# Is there a way to turn on/off xerces "features" via a System Property?

Tags: xml

The apache java xerces xml parser has a number of features (http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html) that control the behavior of the parser. Is there a way to turn these on or off by setting a java System Property?

Answer (score 1):

According to the JAXP 1.5 [Documentation](https://jaxp.java.net/1.5/JAXP1.5Guide.html#JAXP1.5Documentation,Guide-7.3UsingSystemProperties) it is possible:

Found the following example there:

```
  //allow resolution of external schemas

  System.setProperty("javax.xml.accessExternalSchema", "file, http");

   //this setting will affect all processing after it's set
   some processing here

   //after it's done, clear the property
   System.clearProperty("javax.xml.accessExternalSchema");
```

Comment: Setting system properties affects the current JVM. Therefore sometimes it is better to set the properties via API. Properties can be overridden in a way that is documented at https://jaxp.java.net/1.5/JAXP1.5Guide.html#JAXP1.5Documentation%2CGuide-6.PropertySettingsintheJDK